# multiple sources for item in biblatex file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a paper (with year, title and so on) which was later published in a collection of the authors work in a book.
Is it possible to include both as one item in biblatex? 
Like

[1] Author: "Title", Journal, Number, Year(paper), Pages; Booktitle , Year (book), ....

or anything similar.
Sorry if this question has been answered, trying to search for it beared no result.

Comment: Use the enty type `set`

Comment: thank you, the set did the job. didn't realize the overview I found was incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibentryset{aristotle}{%
  aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric}

\begin{document}
    foo.~\cite{aristotle}.
    bar.~\cite{set}% defined in the biblatex-examples.bib
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, the set did the job